# How to interrupt a screen reader in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, accessibility, wai-aria, screen-readers, nwjs

I'm writing a nwjs game, and I want to add accessibility features to it.

I'm currently using the `aria-live` property to communicate with the screen reader.
`document.getElementById("game").setAttribute("aria-live", "assertive")`

and I announce messages by doing
`document.getElementById("game").setAttribute("aria-label", "my text")`

This works, but I need a way to interrupt it.

Both "assertive" and "polite" aria-live settings dont work.
I tried setting the label text to "" or ". !" but it doesn't work either.

Is there a way do do that? Or maybe there's a better way to communicate with the screen reader in a nwjs javascript application?

Comment: accessibility should rarely be solved through JS. Interrupting screen readers does not raise accessibility but lowers it as it causes confusion to the user. If it is about a game, then check first if the game can be accessible through screen readers in the first place. For example, a Flight Simulator can never be accessible to blind gamers. You never can tell a blind person the necessary details at a speed that would be required to fly an aircraft. It would be wasted effort and resources to try to make a flight simulator accessible for those screen readers.

Comment: I'm sure it can be done for this game. I have a implementation that uses the Web Speech API, but Im wondering if I should implement screen reader support. Interrupting is helpful accually, since you can interrupt a long text like a description, scroll thorugh menus faster, etc

Comment: Isn't there some `aria-alert`-like property that interrupts? I vaguely remember something like that for when an alert of notification comes up, and it gets results instantly? It's been a long while though and `aria` is still terrible documented.

Comment: @tacoshy some accesibility experts pointed out your're compleatly wrong about Flight Simulator beaing inaccesible. Please watch this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kpzdzxyqwA0&plid=PLVEo4bPIUOskja9pfpqceY8qDrykFdubf&index=6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the live property isn't taken into account, and so won't work, if aria-live attribute is added after the element is created.
In order to make it work, **the attribute must be present at the time the element is added to the DOM**.

It even doesn't work all the time either if the element is added to the DOM after page load (some screen readers + browsers + OS combinations don't support it).
The safest / most compatible is to have **the live element already present since page load**.

Secondly, the text to be spoken must be added to the live element as content / sub-elements. Use appendChild, insertAdjacentHTML, etc.

A change in the label and/or description won't be read automatically, and it's the same whether it's a real `<label>`, aria-label or aria-labelledby.
Only the **content of the element** will be read.

Note also that **the content present inside the element at page load won't be read**. At least, it doesn't work universally either. If you need to say something right at page load, the trick is to add the content a short time after the page is loaded, just a few hundreds of milliseconds later.

Finally, to answer to the actual question, no, you can't interrupt what the screen reader is currently saying. Clearing the content of the live region will work with a few SR+Browser+OS combinations, but it's quite a large minority.
It doesn't work universally everywhere, so you shouldn't rely on it.

However, if you are making an application with Elektron or nw.js, you have the possibility to call a native library which will interact directly with the screen reader.
Advantages: there is a little less delay when sending a message to speak, and you have effectively control on when to interrupt speech or not.
Drawbacks: it isn't portable, and you may need to call as many different APIs as there are screen readers+OS combinations to support.

If you are interested, I'm the author of such a library for windows, it's called UniversalSpeech. It's callable from nw.js/Elektron.

Answer (score 0):

You could also check out some of the existing [ARIA roles](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#role_definitions) that have some nice defaults. Like role="alert", role="log"..

And what QuentinC said, best to have the attribute in the DOM before adding/removing any content. Also aim to have the live region related attribute on the nearest parent container. Screen readers can struggle with deep DOM trees/updates.